# Is there a way to align a button so that it is not all the way to the right?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and I am trying to align the button so it is right underneath the image. I have used   tags and given a class name so I can then use this in css. However, the only values I know to put for 'text-align' is 'center', 'right' or 'left'.  I tried using pixels (like 30px) but that wasn't working.  I've provided an image of how part of the website looks like below.

css:

```
.imgButton{
     text-align:right;
 }
```

html:

```
<img id="course-image2" src ="https://www.dhresource.com/0x0/f2/albu/g8/M00/2D/C9/rBVaVFz-C7KAY4jwAAEi8hE3J14252.jpg/men-suit-men-tuxedo-custom-made-wedding-suits.jpg" width="260" height="500" alt="guy2" class="center"/>
  
  <div class="imgButton">
      <button class="check">Gentleman</button>
  </div>
```

Image (note the 'Gentleman' button in the far right corner):

[image]

Comment: but that button in whatever container the images are using instead of being separate.

Comment: <div>
          <img id="course-image2" src ="https://www.dhresource.com/0x0/f2/albu/g8/M00/2D/C9/rBVaVFz-C7KAY4jwAAEi8hE3J14252.jpg/men-suit-men-tuxedo-custom-made-wedding-suits.jpg" width="260" height="500" alt="guy2" class="center"/>
      
          <button class="check">Gentleman</button>
      </div>

Comment: You mean within a div that is inside the img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping both the img and button with a container and using flexbox to set the direction of items to be in a column.

```css
.imgContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
  
  <div class="imgContainer">
      <img id="course-image2" src ="https://www.dhresource.com/0x0/f2/albu/g8/M00/2D/C9/rBVaVFz-C7KAY4jwAAEi8hE3J14252.jpg/men-suit-men-tuxedo-custom-made-wedding-suits.jpg" width="260" height="500" alt="guy2" class="center"/>
      <div class="imgButton">
        <button class="check">Gentleman</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```